# SELECT Top Five Opportunities

Tags: soql

I want to select the top five opportunities. To determine top five I multiple Opportunity.Amount by Opportunity.Probability for every Opportunity and then pick out the top results.

I was hoping to do:

```
SELECT AccountId, Amount, Probability, (Amount * Probability) weightedProbability FROM Opportunity order by weightedProbability limit 5
```

which fails because it does not like:

```
(Amount * Probability) weightedProbability
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SFDC already calculates Amount * Probability for you on the Opportunity, and stores it in the Expected Revenue field.

Answer (score 4):

I would be tempted to write a formula field which performs the calculation (Amount * Probability) and then reference that in your SOQL query.

e.g.

```
SELECT AccountId, Amount, Probability, weightedProbability__c FROM Opportunity order by weightedProbability__c limit 5
```

Comment: lol, i will remove my answer ;)

Comment: @Phil Hawthorn Thanks. I'd like to be able to do it without touching the schema. Is that possible? It is in SQL but just wondering about SOQL.

Comment: hmm, not that I know of I'm afraid. @mast0r, great minds think alike ;)